# Where is the database for Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal

I' am on the learning process of Drupal 7. When installing Drupal 7 I have used MySQLI database option, where it didn't ask me any information about my database. After installation was complete. I went to my Database to check if database was automatically created, it wasn't.

I wanted to know where and how does Drupal 7 uses database.

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/310071

Answer (score 1):

Drupal configuration files is normally located in:

```
sites/default/settings.php
```

Which gets populated during installation process (usually copied from default.settings.php). In regards to the database - you need to create one beforehand (if you start a new project). Please, refer to INSTALL.txt in the root of Drupal package. There is a step-by-step instruction that explains the process.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If it successfully installed there sure must be a database somewhere :) When you install Drupal 7 it will determine what database types you have available and require you to input at least the database TYPE, and NAME.

If this information was not asked of you during the installation process then there is only one thing that I can think of; the settings file already has some database settings in there.

So I suggest looking in the place already mentioned:
/**yourdrupalfolder**/sites/default/settings.php
And have a hunt for an array that contains all the database information.

Hopefully that file will let you understand what happened!